# First mock of the method applied always

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito

I want to test a few cases in a method by mocking external dependency to return different results for every test case. But `when` always returns what is defined at first time (in this example - empty set) and that brokes the next tests.
If I run tests one by one they pass successfully but when I run the whole class only the first test pass and others fail.

Testing class:

```java
class ExampleTest {

    @Mock
    private Dao dao;

    @Mock
    private Validator validator;

    @Spy
    @InjectMocks
    Controller controller;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        initMocks(this);
    }

    private final static Set DATA = Set.of("data1", "data2");

    @Test
    void firstTest() throws UserDashboardException, DashboardException, WidgetException {
        when(validator.filter(DATA)).thenReturn(Collections.emptySet());

        assertThrows(Exception.class, () -> controller.create(DATA));
    }

    @Test
    void secondTest() throws UserDashboardException, DashboardException, WidgetException {
        when(validator.filter(DATA)).thenReturn(DATA);

        controller.create(DATA);

        verify(dao, times(1)).create(eq(DATA));
    }

}
```

Tested class:

```java
public class Controller {

    private Dao dao;
    private Validator validator;

    public Controller(Dao dao,Validator validator) {
        this.dao = dao;
        this.validator = validator;
    }

    public String create(Set<String> data) {
        data = validator.filter(data);

        if (data.isEmpty()) {
            throw new Exception("Invalid data.");
        }

    return dao.create(data);
    }
}
```

So, in both tests `create` method throws an exception which is not what I expect. Maybe I miss some point?

Comment: Your `secondTest` isn't testing anything.

Comment: @M.Deinum, thanks but this is only typo in the example. ;) There are no syntax errors. Just the test fails because of unexpected result of filter() method.

Comment: Then please provide a valid sample... Your current `secondTest` doesn;t call the controller and hence the verify will always fail. So not just a typo but rather a crucial part of the test method that is missing.

Comment: @M.Deinum, fixed. I'm just trying to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: Your first when can be removed (as returning an empty list is the default). If it still fails then  your predicate doesn't match and Mockito will return the default answer which is an empty collections. I suspect that the `Set.of` returns a `Set` implementation that when checked with `equals` is being returned `false`.

Comment: @M.Deinum, this is not a decision and doesn't help me to understand why this happening.

Comment: I'm trying to let you understand the [default behavior](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.1.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_DEFAULTS). The default for a Set is to return an emtpy Set. So the `when(validator.filter(DATA)).thenReturn(Collections.emptySet());` is redundant as an empty set is the default behavior. This part `when(validator.filter(DATA))` is the key. This matcher will trigger the `thenReturn`. However I suspect that the `Set.of` method returns a `Set` that returns `false` when `equals` is being called. Making the no match and thus returning the default.

Comment: Would also be interesting if the `create(...)` method on the `Controller` is actually the `getById()` method, or if we are looking at the wrong code...

Comment: Why do you have the `@Spy` annotation on your subject under test? Use the real object for testing - and in fact, `@Spy` is pretty much always a bad sign.

Comment: @M.Deinum, it looks you are right that first when is redundant and the second is returning an empty set. But to make it return what I want? How to build the set that I want as a result?

Comment: Try `when(validator.filter(anySet())` instead of `when(validator.filter(DATA))`, that should match regardless of what is being passed in.

Comment: @M.Deinum, unfortunately, it didn't help. What I forgot to mention is that if I run test one by one they pass successfully (even with Set.of()) but when I run the whole class only first test pass and others fails.

Comment: That is quite important to know, please add that information to your question. Also why do you need an `@Spy` on your `Controller` field? And are you using the proper annotations on your class? Looks like you are using JUnit5 make sure you aren't mixing in JUnit4 annotations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried with doReturn method?

```
doReturn(DATA).when(validator).filter(DATA)
```

which can be import from org.mockito.Mockito.doReturn;

Edited: there might be a bug inside your code implementation:

```
data = validator.filter(data);
```

Comment: Yes, but result is the same. :/

Comment: I have looked at your code again. It seems like there is a bug in your code.

`data = validator.filter(data);`

In here, the first test run will return and make your data become empty, but the underlying DATA will also be empty.

Comment: Exactly! Thank you very much!